# How to redefine python3 MagicMock magic method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking

I need to redefine `MagicMock's` magic method in the child class and then use child class for testing, so I've tried:

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock


class MockForTest(MagicMock):
    def __lt__(self):
        return self


t1 = MockForTest()
print(t1.__lt__())  # prints NotImplemented
```

But why `NotImplemented`? I know I can do it:

```
class A():
    def __lt__(self):
        return NotImplemented


class B(A):
    def __lt__(self):
        return self


b = B()
print(b.__lt__())  # prints <__main__.B object at 0x000001D6EE77B2B0>
```

So, I can't redefine `MagicMock`'s magic methods?

Comment: What is the behaviour you're actually trying to test with this? *"I need to redefine `MagicMock`'s magic method in the child class and then use child class for testing"* - why?

Comment: I need to test some api endpoint. That endpoint calls external database, so I want to simulate external database Models using Mocks. I can't use t1.__lt__.return_value = 'lol' because there is some serialization that creates another Mocks inside object

Comment: Perhaps you could include some context in the question? It's possibly an http://xyproblem.info

Comment: I guess that the cause that your implementation is removed is at https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4002d5dbf4c058bbf2462f9f5dea057956d1caff/Lib/unittest/mock.py#L1834 `MagicMixInx` remove all other magic impls.

Comment: ... but you can use `t1.__lt__.return_value = t1`

Answer (score 0):

You can use instead

`t1.__lt__.return_value = t1`

From what I can understand from https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4002d5dbf4c058bbf2462f9f5dea057956d1caff/Lib/unittest/mock.py#L1834 `MagicMixin` remove all other magic methods.